# memory allocation failed, out of memory. SBF program panicked

Tags: cpi

I have a program that makes ~20 cross program invocations (CPIs). On one CPI it fails when calling [process_instruction](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.16.1/program-runtime/src/invoke_context.rs#L749-L759), stating it ran out of memory. Logs below

```
    Program log: Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory
    Program XYZ consumed 363770 of 800000 compute units
    Program XYZ failed: SBF program panicked
```

I have used the compute budget program to even change the heap from 32kb to `256 * 1024 = 262_144 bytes`, but that had zero effect on the issue. So I've ruled out the actual heap frame from the invoke context as the issue and think it has to be some other memory piece in [rbpf](https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf). Is there some memory aspect of CPIs that does not get dropped on new calls and continually bloats?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since it seems like you're doing everything right. If you want to totally rule out heap allocations, you can define your own allocator and log a message during every allocation to see how much you've used. There's an example program doing that at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/examples/rust/custom-heap

Comment: I wrote my own custom Allocator that frees up some space. I'm not posting that as an answer because it's unsafe if used incorrectly. Through the process it does seem like the ComputeBudget's request heap size instruction does not have the intended affect. Can never get something bigger than 32kb (trying to access outside gives access violations).